# Convert form into object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Using node.js and express...say there is a form with these fields:

```
<form action="/test" method="post">
    <input name="name" value="zzz" />
    <input name="test[0].name" value="a" />
    <input name="test[0].value" value="b" />
    <input name="test[1].name" value="c" />
    <input name="test[1].value" value="d" />
</form>
```

And when submitted to node the `req.body` object is like this:

```
{
    'name': 'zzz'
    'test[0].name': 'a',
    'test[0].value': 'b',
    'test[1].name': 'c',
    'test[1].value': 'd'
}
```

How do I get an object like this instead?

```
{
    'name: 'zzz',
    'test': [
        { 'name': 'a', 'value': 'b'},
        { 'name': 'c', 'value': 'd'}
    ]
}
```

That is an object where the form is parsed into an object (like Ruby).

Comment: How is the request's body being parsed on the server? If the `app` is using [`bodyParser.urlencoded()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions), this is the `extended` format.

Comment: Ah got it, seems that the express generated default is `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`